# How to update multiple columns in single update statement with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I want to perform simple update on table **fleet_online_orc** with some data within table **skytrack_data_packet_orc**. Both tables are highlighted below and queries are also given. Please help on it.

```html
fleet_online_orc table
-----------------------

`latitude  longitude  gid   fleet_sim_no  location   ast_updated_time`

`26.8708 80.9568  21444 9828221444    Budshahnagar 2015-03-27 11:56:08.097`
`22.6958 75.8868  27534 9828027534   Samwad Nagar 2015-03-27 11:56:08.097`
`19.0918 72.8822  13458 9259113458   Jari Mari    2015-03-27 11:56:08.097`
```

```
`skytrack_data_packet_orc
-------------------------`

sim_no      latitude    longitude   utc_date   ist_time
9611170088  12.98304    77.59880    200415  2015-04-20 16:35:35.0
9611170088  12.98304    77.59880    200415  2015-04-20 16:35:19.0
9611170088  12.98304    77.59881    200415  2015-04-20 16:35:03.0
```

This is the query which I am trying....

```html
UPDATE fleet_online_orc  tar
SET
tar.al_latitude = src.latitude, 
tar.al_longitude = src.longitude, 
tar.al_location ='Bangalore'
FROM skytrack_data_packet_orc  src
WHERE tar.fleet_sim_no = sor.sim_no
AND tar.gid = 21444;
```

And this the error which I am getting..

```html
UPDATE bd_fleet.fleet_online_orc  tar  
SET tar.al_latitude = sor.latitude, tar.al_longitude = sor.longitude, tar.al_location = 'Bangalore'
FROM bd_fleet.skytrack_data_packet_orc  sor
WHERE tar.fleet_sim_no = sor.sim_no
AND tar.gid = 2089;
MismatchedTokenException(17!=20)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnAssignmentClause(HiveParser.java:42463)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.setColumnsClause(HiveParser.java:42536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.updateStatement(HiveParser.java:42682)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1067)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:34 extraneous input 'tar' expecting SET near 'tar' in update statement
line 2:7 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 'tar' in update statement
~
```

Comment: Which version of hive you are using. Hive support update from 0.14.0 version.

Comment: Yea..the hive version which i am using is greater than 0.14 so it has to update...simple update query like this is working fine..

Comment: UPDATE fleet_online_orc  SET
al_latitude  = 12.77558, 
al_longitude = 77.5625, 
al_location = 'Bangalore'
WHERE gid = 21444;